# plot dataframe columns via for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 6), index=dates, columns=["a","b","c","a_x","b_x","c_x"])
```

which results in the following:

```
                a           b            c         a_x         b_x         c_x
2013-01-01  -0.871681   0.938965    -0.804039   0.329384    -1.211573   0.160477
2013-01-02  1.673895    2.017654    2.181771    0.336220    0.389709    0.246264
2013-01-03  -0.670211   -0.561792   -0.747824   -0.837123   0.129040    1.044153
2013-01-04  -0.571023   -0.430249   0.024393    1.017622    1.072909    0.816249
2013-01-05  0.074952    -0.119953   0.245248    2.658196    -1.525059   1.131054
2013-01-06  0.203816    0.379939    -0.162919   -0.674444   -0.650636   0.415143
```

I want to generate simple line plot charts - a total of three, each plotting the couples:

```
a and a_x, b and b_x and c and c_x
```

I know how to generate charts but since the table is big and has the same pattern in the column naming conventions I was thinking if that is possible to be achieved via for loop. For examples the original table would have a `column d and column d_x`, also `column e and e_x` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` along `axis=1`, grouped by the first element of splitting columns names:

```
for _, data in df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1):
    data.plot()
```

[out]

[image]